# How to detect complex item?

Tags: deep-learning, annotations, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I need to train a deeplearning model, I need to make the model figure out different plants, like maize and wheat, but they look like these:
[maize example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UEGm.jpg)
[wheat example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvhJH.jpg)

I think it's hard to make a deeplearning model like darknet(now I'm using yolov4), does anyone have some good idea?
I don't know how to finish this task.

If detect is useful, which annotation is correct? whole img or split every single feature ?

I used yolov4-tiny, yolov4, but they all perform not good, I have no idea about this